# Inject a view from Module A with an event in Module B - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there anyway to inject a view from Module A with an event in Module ?
Ex : 
I have a create user view in Module Users

```
@extends('backend.master')
@section('content')
<div>
      <input type='email' name='emai'> 
      ...
</div>
```

Now i create another Profile module to add more field like phone,adress,v.v... .And i dont want to touch the User module again ,so i can maintain it more easy later .Anyway to add more field to users module via Event or etc ... without touching the Users module? ?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you send the type of the profile that you want to create from the controller to the view ?

Comment: Ex : Profile extend view profile.blade.view
<input type='phone' name='phone'>
<input type='address' name ='address'>

Comment: From your controller you can sent `$profileType` to the create view and in the User module view you will add just a test to include the other profile view if profileType is the new one like this `@if ($profileType == "newProfile")
   @include('new.profile.view')
@endif`